# Changing a folder icon on an external hard drive not working

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, icons

So I've been putting custom icons on folders for years.  I do it on my desktop.  I do it on any external hard drive folders I have....just for fun and it looks better.

Here is the method I use:

1. Take and save the icon file you want to use for your folder on the external harddirve where the folder is
2. Goto the properties of your folder you want to change it
3. Right click -> Propierties -> Customize -> Change icon
4. Select the path from your icon file you want to use (note that the icon file has to be saved on your external hard dirve where the folder is) in the form
5. Click on "OK" and then on "Apply"

Well, suddenly on one of my external hard drives, this is no longer working.  The folder containing the icons is "in" the hard drive.  I go through the process above and then nothing...just stays the same old yellow windows folder. I attached pic if I did it correctly.  The yellow folder labeled "icons" is where they are located.  The folders that actually have an icon on them are from outside of the external hard drive.

Now, if I use an icon from a source outside the hard drive, my desktop for example, it will change.

[pic example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL6tt.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried the usual general remedies, i.e., rebooting completely, with Fast Startup turned off, and repairing Windows with DISM and SFC?

Comment: Have you verified that a `desktop.in` file was createed and that the folder has its `readOnly` attrubute set? That can only be reliably determined by adding the `Attributes` column to a `Details` view of the parent folder.